# PHP: Output the watermarked image in <img> tag

Tags: php, html, image, watermark

I have successfully watermarked the image as mentioned in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php). It uses `header('Content-type: image/png');` to output the `image`. What I need to do is to output the image in `html` `<img>` tags. how can I accomplish that? any idea?

Comment: Well, how does one reference images in an `<img>` tag? By providing its url in the `src` property, obviously. So what is the question here?

Comment: How I wish I could up vote your comment more.

Comment: You probably didn't bother to look at the manual. My question was to what to paste in the `src` of `<img>` @arkascha

Comment: What manual? The html documentation? I am pretty certain I did use the `src` property correct in the description above... You specify a url that delivers the image you want to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="/url/to/your/image-making-file-goes-here.php" alt="Image created by php" />
```

You should probably use some cache for this too.